# what does push ecx do?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I see code with `push ecx` and I don't know its purpose. Does it change the value of ecx to something else?

Comment: Rather than filling mindless copy-paste into your question, you should have written something about which contexts you see this instruction in and what you already know about assembly language.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But that requires effort, we can't have that!

Comment: +1 for the name of the handle

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP isn't a troll.  Anyone seeing push ecx in assembly would also have seen dozens of other instructions that would be equally mysterious if one didn't know what push does.  In any case, the only legitimate answer to this question is RTFM.

Answer (score 15):

It pushes the value of `ecx` on the stack.  `ecx` is a x86 CPU register, which can hold a value of a certain amount of bits (32 or 64 (called `rcx` then) on modern x86 CPU's).

The *call stack* is divided into *stack frames*.  Stack frames are created when a function is called, the parameters are pushed on the stack that are passed to the function, then the function is executed. While the function is running, local function variables are also stored on the the stack by using `push` and `pop`.  `push` puts *something on the stack*, and `pop` *takes the thing that was last put on it, back off*.

You have to imagine the stack like a stack of plates, you put one on top, (push) and then you take that same one off again (pop) before you can reach the next one underneath.

The functions that have led to the function currently running, are all on this stack, and sit "underneath" if you like, the current functions stack frame.  When the current function returns, it's popped off the stack (stack frame destroyed) and the caller function can continue where it left off.

I've simplified some bits, for the sake of this explanation.

Comment: `ecx` is always 32 bits, `rcx` would be the x86-64 64 bit equivalent.

Comment: @PaulR I made a small edit on my post. :)

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill I didn't say that `push` or `ecx` have any notion of a stack frame. I was trying to explain them using stack frame as an example. That doesn't mean that they always coexist.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: regarding the lack of info in the question it is too much of an example, if you ask me... no offense, but I think it would've been enough to give that comparison with a stack of plates, where you --- quite reasonably --- omitted the possibility of indexed access.